# Dockerize FastAPI + Ray - Ray stop after container run

Tags: docker, fastapi, ray

I trying to dockerize this app FastAPI combine with "Ray", the issue is Ray instance stopped after the Dockerfile finished the building. kindly check the attached below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVbso.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHoED.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5xdD.jpg)

Dockerfile:

FROM python:3.10.5

WORKDIR /app/

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1

COPY . .

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install pipenv

RUN pip3 install "ray[serve]"

ADD Pipfile.* /app/

RUN pipenv install --dev

WORKDIR /app/

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8888
EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 8265

ENV NLP_HOST=0.0.0.0

ENV NLP_PORT=8888

ENTRYPOINT [ "ray", "start", "--head" ]

### CMD [ ".venv/bin/python", "serve_with_fastapi.py" ]

> Successfully built 196cd1ca73ce
> Successfully tagged nlp:latest
> Creating nlp ... done
> Attaching to nlp
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:26:59,888        INFO usage_lib.py:320 -- Usage stats collection is enabled by default without user confirmation because this stdin is detected to be non-interactively. To disable this, add `--disable-usage-stats` to the command that starts the cluster, or run the following command: `ray disable-usage-stats` before starting the cluster. See https://docs.ray.io/en/master/cluster/usage-stats.html for more details.
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:26:59,888        INFO scripts.py:715 -- Local node IP: 172.26.0.2
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:01,942        INFO services.py:1470 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:01,945        WARNING services.py:2002 -- WARNING: The object store is using /tmp instead of /dev/shm because /dev/shm has only 67108864 bytes available. This will harm performance! You may be able to free up space by deleting files in /dev/shm. If you are inside a Docker container, you can increase /dev/shm size by passing '--shm-size=4.91gb' to 'docker run' (or add it to the run_options list in a Ray cluster config). Make sure to set this to more than 30% of available RAM.
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,261        SUCC scripts.py:757 -- --------------------
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,261        SUCC scripts.py:758 -- Ray runtime started.
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,261        SUCC scripts.py:759 -- --------------------
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:761 -- Next steps
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:762 -- To connect to this Ray runtime from another node, run
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:765 --   ray start --address='172.26.0.2:6379'
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:770 -- Alternatively, use the following Python code:
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:772 -- import ray
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:776 -- ray.init(address='auto')
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:788 -- To connect to this Ray runtime from outside of the cluster, for example to
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:792 -- connect to a remote cluster from your laptop directly, use the following
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:796 -- Python code:
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,262        INFO scripts.py:798 -- import ray
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,263        INFO scripts.py:799 -- ray.init(address='ray://<head_node_ip_address>:10001')
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,263        INFO scripts.py:808 -- If connection fails, check your firewall settings and network configuration.
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,263        INFO scripts.py:816 -- To terminate the Ray runtime, run
> nlp    | 2022-06-22 21:27:02,263        INFO scripts.py:817 --   ray stop
> nlp exited with code 0

Comment: Could you share the application code as well? Ideally a minimal example and docker image the reproduce the issue. However, if you are just running Ray in a single machine, you don't need to run `ray start`. Instead, you can just do `ray.init()` in your application code.

Comment: Do not use images for including relevant details to your question; images are not searchable, have bad accessibility, can't be copy-pasted and requires the user to switch between multiple contexts when reading.